# How to add save-exact in bunfig.toml?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bun

Is there an equivalent to .npmrc config `save-exact` in bun?

I tried to add

```ini
save-exact = true
```

to bunfig.toml but it does not work.

I use bun version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems now `bunfig` supports a static config option to use exact dependencies, additional to the cli option: `bun add --exact ...`

### install.exact

Whether to set an exact version in package.json. Default `false`.

By default Bun uses caret ranges; if the latest version of a package is 2.4.1, the version range in your package.json will be ^2.4.1. This indicates that any version from 2.4.1 up to (but not including) 3.0.0 is acceptable.

sample `bunfig.toml`:

```ini
[install]
exact = true
```

Here is the source from the bun official documentation site:
https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/bunfig#install-exact

I hope this is what you are looking for

Update:

I tried this myself, and apparently the config is supported but not working, at least on my end.
I will fallback for now to add the parameter `--exact` while installing packages, and I will be reporting the status of the functionality with each `bun` version.

`bun` version tested: `1.0.2`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `bun` does not support a functionality like `--save-exact` for now.

You can try to create your own tool to replace versions that start with `~` or `^` with "".